# Replacement for isInstance() method when deploying to web in libgdx

Tags: java, gradle, gwt, libgdx

I'm making a game with libGDX that I want to export to HTML using Gradle. The issue comes when I use this method to get a list of actors. Apparently `isInstance()` and `isInstanceOf` are not compatible with GWT so I'm looking for a way to get around this. Gradle tell me `isInstance` is not defined. It runs fine on desktop.

```
public static ArrayList<BaseActor> getList(Stage stage, String className) {
    ArrayList<BaseActor> list = new ArrayList<BaseActor>();

    Class theClass = null;
    try {
        theClass = ClassReflection.forName("com.mygdx.game.actors." + className);
    } catch (Exception error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Actor a : stage.getActors()) {
        if (theClass.isInstance(a))
            list.add((BaseActor) a);

    }
        return list;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Actor class has a user object property (`getUserObject()`/`setUserObject()`) that you can use to attach data. You could make your BaseActor use this as a class tag property, and use an abstract method so you won't forget to add it to any of your Actor implementations.

```
abstract class BaseActor {

    //...

    public BaseActor() {
        setUserObject(getClassTag());
        //...
    }

    protected abstract String getClassTag();

}
```

```
class SomeSpecificActor extends BaseActor {

    public SomeSpecificActor () {
        super();
        //...
    }

    @Override 
    protected String getClassTag() {
        return "SomeSpecificActor";
    }
}
```

```
public static ArrayList<BaseActor> getList(Stage stage, String classTag) {
    ArrayList<BaseActor> list = new ArrayList<BaseActor>();

    for (Actor a : stage.getActors()) {
        if (classTag.equals(a.getUserObject()))
            list.add((BaseActor) a);
    }
    return list;

}
```

Comment: However, if you indeed use the `getClassTag()` you can just compare `classTag` with the `getClassTag()` and not use the `get/setUserObject()` at all.

Comment: @MaanooAk Not without casting the Actors to BaseActor. Might be OK if the stage has exclusively BaseActors in it, but then you can’t even use Groups.